# Лист из виджетов

Tags: c++, qt5, qwidget

Потребность сделать лист из кастомных виджетов.

У меня есть идея, просто создать дочернее окно и туда запихать все виджеты, но возможно есть и другие методы и виджеты для этого дела. Я пробовал издеваться над `QListWidget`, `QListView`. Есть ли другие более подходящие способы для этого?

p.s. Исходный код в вопрос смысла добавлять не вижу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему с помощью `QMDIArea` в качестве листа для кастомных виджетов.
p.s. Чебуреки, которые ставят минусы, выпучив глаза, только потому что у них ЧСВ играет, вместо того, чтобы помочь - вам отдельный физкульт привет, это моя последний вопрос и ответ на данном ресурсе из-за таких обезьян не хочется больше не помогать тут, не задавать вопросы)

Comment: @Kromster по какой причине тему закрыл?